# Eclipse, jython : adding numpy module to jython

Tags: python

i have a problem while installing numpy-1.6.1.It says `NotImplementedError` i use eclipse and jython for developing.

**Command window:**

```
C:\Program Files\jython2.5.3b3\bin\numpy-1.6.1>jython setup.py install
```

Running from numpy source directory.Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "setup.py", line 196, in <module>
    setup_package()

  File "setup.py", line 173, in setup_package
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup

  File "C:\Program Files\jython2.5.3b3\bin\numpy-1.6.1\numpy\distutils\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ccompiler
  File "C:\Program Files\jython2.5.3b3\bin\numpy-1.6.1\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 15, in <module>
    from numpy.distutils.exec_command import exec_command

  File "C:\Program Files\jython2.5.3b3\bin\numpy-1.6.1\numpy\distutils\exec_command.py", line 585, in <module>
    raise NotImplementedError('exec_command tests for ', os.name)

NotImplementedError: ('exec_command tests for ', 'java')
```

Would you be so kind as to help me solving this problem? Thank you!

Comment: since `numpy` is a **C-extension**, I highly doubt that it'll run on Java's virtual machine via `jython` (but someone might prove me wrong ... I don't know much about java).  There is significant effort to port (at least parts of it) to PyPy though ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, `numpy` isn't supported on Jython. From the [FAQ](http://scipy.github.com/faq.html#does-numpy-scipy-work-with-jython):

> Does NumPy/SciPy work with Jython?
>
> No. Simply put, Jython runs on top of the Java Virtual Machine and has no way to interface with extensions written in C for the standard Python (CPython) interpreter.